# Camunda parse date from JavaScript-Date

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

Trying to parse the date-string in Camunda-Javascript I get the following error:

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: Cannot serialize object in variable 'xy': SPIN/DOM-XML-01030 Cannot create context
```

Trying to return only a Date the error is also thrown:

[image]

returning only the String it gets interpret as "String":

```js
json.briefdatum;
```

[image]

So how can I return the date-string as "Camunda"-Date?

Answer (score 1):

So, after a long time of experimenting I found the solution:

```js
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS";
var mydate= json.mydate;
briefdatum ? new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(mydate) : "";
```

This JavaScript in `output parameter` of the  `http-connector` parses the date (if present).